# Text spinner failing upon given multiple conditions

Tags: python

So I am trying to create a simple text spinner that allows you to create sentences based on a given input. I tried replicating the text spinner from here: http://sp1n.me/index.html. After a little bit of researching I put together the code below:

```
import re
import itertools

def options(s):
    if len(s) > 0 and s[0] == '{':
        return [opt for opt in s[1:-1].split('|')]
    return [s] 

comment ="sp1n.me is a {{beautiful |}{{content |}text |}{spinner|generator}|{wonderful |}{service|tool}} which {allows you to|can} {easily|recursively} {spin|rotate|generate} {text|text content|content}."
chunk = re.split('(\{[^\}]+\}|[^\{\}]*)',comment)

opt_lists = [options(frag) for frag in chunk]

for spec in itertools.product(*opt_lists):
    print((''.join(spec)))
```

However, it does not really work how the spinner from sp1n.me does. My output looks like this:

```
sp1n.me is a text |}generator|tool} which can recursively rotate content.
sp1n.me is a text |}generator|tool} which can recursively generate text.
sp1n.me is a text |}generator|tool} which can recursively generate text content.
sp1n.me is a text |}generator|tool} which can recursively generate content.
```

When it actually was supposed to look clean, like this:

```
sp1n.me is a service which can recursively rotate text.
sp1n.me is a beautiful spinner which allows you to recursively spin text content.
sp1n.me is a wonderful text generator which can easily spin text content.
```

What tweaks are there to be made in my code so that it will work properly like the one from the site that I have mentioned? Basically the problem is that the code does not allow optional phrases like: `The quick{ red|} fox...`

Comment: So you want to be able to replace service with "beautiful spinner" or "wonderful text generator"?

Comment: I don't think you quite understood what the actual code does. It's not about replacing anything. It is about generating text from different given options.

Comment: If you visit the actual spin.me site you linked, there are the terms "replacements", "replacements per hole", and replacements rate."

Comment: Yeah, honestly, I have no idea what are those. Let's focus solely on my piece of code; I am looking for an improvement for it so that it will be able to allow optional phrases so that my output won't look like `|}generator|tool}`. The way sp1n.me is made, it allows you to insert multiple options for the text to be generated on, compared to my code where only `{option1|option2}` works.